# How to install a package in collaboratory using `python setup.py install`

Tags: google-colaboratory

Right now, I have

```
!wget myPackage
!tar -xvjf myPackage
!cd myPackage && python setup.py install
```

**All of which complete**, but then

```
import myPackage
```

fails. That seems likely to be because the python which I call with `!python setup.py` is different than the python which executes each cell. How do I install a package using `!python setup.py install` such that I'm able to import the package?

I tried `!which python` which gave me `/usr/local/bin/python` but `/usr/local/bin/python setup.py install` had the same issue, which seems reasonable.

Also see: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb

Comment: Please share a precise problem statement. (What is `myPackage`?)

Comment: @BobSmith my package is pyRosetta. See this notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1f75uvnJrf9JRjFaqTGoAoj6FuIxoi2y6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart your Python runtime after the install using the Runtime -> Restart runtime... menu.

Here's a worked example:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z1d5IGStWkqGXMk_txdxTngDXMkxcDOh

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wonder: since this installation is fairly non-trivial, is there a way to preserve state with collab notebooks? Say I close this notebook and then re-open it. Is the package still installed? If not normally, is there a way to set a flag that it should?

Comment: I'm also wondering if there is a way without restarting